# How to validate username and password using array in

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi I would like to make a login screen wherein the user will input a username and password.but how do I validate it using an array? please help thank you

```
        int[] username = { 807301, 992032, 123144 ,123432};

        string[] password = {"Miami", "LosAngeles" ,"NewYork" ,"Dallas"};

        if (username[0].ToString() == password[0])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("equal");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not equal");
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (userName == username[0].ToString() && password == password[0]) {}` , where `userName` and `password` is user input?

Comment: yes youre correct thank you! but how do I check other index?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the index of the username first from your array `username`. Then based on that index compare the password from password array.

```
int[] username = { 807301, 992032, 123144, 123432 };

string[] password = { "Miami", "LosAngeles", "NewYork", "Dallas" };

int enteredUserName = 123144;
string enteredPassword = "NewYork";

//find the index from the username array
var indexResult = username.Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i })
                          .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Value == enteredUserName);
if (indexResult == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid user name");
    return;
}

int indexOfUserName = indexResult.Index;

//Compare the password from that index. 
if (indexOfUserName < password.Length && password[indexOfUserName] == enteredPassword)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User authenticated");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid password");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use a dictionary? A dictionary is some kind of array but it combines matching keys and values. `TryGetValue` will try to look up the username. If no username is found, the function will return `false` otherwise it will return `true` and the matching password. This password can be used to validate the password entered by the user.

```
Dictionary<int, string> userCredentials = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {807301, "Miami"},
    {992032, "LosAngeles"},
    {123144, "NewYork"},
    {123432 , "Dallas"},
};

int userName = ...;
string password = ...;

string foundPassword;
if (userCredentials.TryGetValue(userName, out foundPassword) && (foundPassword == password))
{
    Console.WriteLine("User authenticated");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid password");
}
```